# Audit Events language

Tags: docusignapi

I'am using Docusign API.

Is there a way to change the language when calling the API for audit events of an enveloppe ?

Audit events are all the events that has happened in the enveloppe history.

I'am calling this url

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents

I can't find a parameter to set the language of the response.

Even if an enveloppe have been generated in another language, the result will be in english.
The account calling the API is also set to the correct language.

The goal here is to build an history page of an enveloppe in a third party application.

On Docusign pages this content (show history of an envelope) is translated but using the API, i can't find a correct answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have receive an anwser from Docusign technical team :

API responses are english only.